# Exchange Online: Security group not showing on shared mailbox delegation for full access or send as permissions

Tags: permissions, office365, exchange

I am trying to give a security group (created on premise AD and synced to Azure AD) permissions to a shared mailbox in 365.

I added myself to the security group. Used powershell to give myself permissions on the shared mailbox. This is the script for full access and a second script for send as permissions.

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity  sharedmailbox@domain.com -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All -AutoMapping:$false -User  "security group name"  -Confirm:$false
```

When I check the delegation tab on the shared mailbox, I see that the security group has been added.
When I try to add the security group manually, I am not able to find the security group. Can only find users and not groups to give permissions.

That means that I can't access the shared mailbox till I give myself permissions as user.

Does anyone knows how I can give a security group access to a shared mailbox and access the shared mailbox? Because I am getting a access denied when I use the security group.

Answer (score 0):

Has this security group been synchronized to Azure AD? Try to run **Synchronization Service Manager** as Administrator and see that:

[image]

And check if the group shows in Azure AD(**[All Groups in Azure AD](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/GroupsManagementMenuBlade/AllGroups)**), if this group doesn't show in AAD, check if it locates the synchronized OU and run delta sync again.

If this group has shown in AAD, there may be a delay of synchronization between Exchange Online and Azure AD. You may need wait for a while until the group shows in the group list in EAC.

Comment: Hi @ivan_wang thank you for your answer. The synchronisation is succesfully completed last week. The groups are showing in Azure AD and I see myself also as a member in one of the groups. I was able to add the certain group to the shared mailbox by using Powershell and that works (I also see the group listed on the delegation tab). But when I look in de Admin center / Teams and groups / Shared mailbox / open the properties of the mailbox, I can't see the Security Group. When I go to Exchange portal and check the shared mailbox properties, then I can see the Security Group under the delegation

Comment: Does this security group show in the following location? **Admin center / Active teams & groups / Mail-enabled security**. Try to access Admin center with incognito mode and see if there is any difference.

Comment: @Sercan Hi, it's been a while, is there any update?

Comment: Hi, it seems that it isn't possible to use security groups with shared mailbox. I have added them with a script. Thank you for your tim.e

Comment: I'm glad that you've fixed the ACL issue. If everything works well, you could share your solutions and mark the best answer to finish this thread. Have a good day!